# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, nullpointerexception, program-entry-point

my code is :

```
import ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.model.FNSense;
import ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.model.FNSynset;
import ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.model.FNSynsetsRelation;
import ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.service.FNSynsetService;
import java.util.Vector;
public class sample2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FNSynsetService service=new FNSynsetService();
        service.findAll();
       }
}
```

and when I run it display this error

> ```
>    Data Load Started...
>    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.dao.FNWordDao.getTextNode(FNWordDao.java:513)
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.dao.FNWordDao.loadWords(FNWordDao.java:438)
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.dao.FNWordDao.<init>(FNWordDao.java:76)
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.dao.FNDaoManager.<init>(FNDaoManager.java:25)
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.data.dao.FNDaoManager.getInstance(FNDaoManager.java:40)
>    at ir.sbu.nlp.wordnet.service.FNSynsetService.<init>(FNSynsetService.java:51)
>    at sample2.main(sample2.java:12)
> ```

Can every one help me?
I copy every file needed for installation

Comment: Post the `FNSynsetService` class source :)

Comment: Post the `FNWordDao` class.

Comment: Use a debugger to figure out what is null.

Comment: Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found.
I recieve this messsage when I debug it.

My problem is I cant see code of library. There is compiled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to set some object before calling service.findAll();

While this method is executing it might be trying to access some object which is turning out to be null. Debug and find out the exact line which is throwing NPE.

Comment: tnx. My problem is I cant see code of library. There is compiled code.

Comment: then the data is corrupted..

Comment: It run successfully on other pcs but on my laptop dont

Comment: NPE is in DAO. Very likely you are getting nothing from DB. Make sure you are connected properly to DB. Where is the code for connecting to DB or other Data Source ?

Comment: Every task is done in my libraries. My problem is I cant see code of library. There is compiled code.

Comment: Well. Then either your DB connection should be in constructor of FNSynsetService. If not , you have to do it manually, which is missing here.

Comment: It run successfully on other pcs but on my laptop dont.I think there isnt any problem in my code.